# How to take screenshot of webview in Android

Tags: android, html, canvas, webview

I have drawn some lines on html5 canvas within webview and tried to take screenshot of the webview using below code...

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/myfolder");
if(!myFile.exists()) {
    myFile.mkdir();
}
imagePath = myFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/myimage001.png";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
    if ( fos != null ) {
        screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
} catch( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I open that image then it looks empty. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Do as follows

```
private void TakeScreenshot()
{
 Picture picture = webview.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

                    picture.draw( c );
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {

                        fos = new FileOutputStream( "mnt/sdcard/yahoo.jpg" );
                            if ( fos != null )
                            {
                                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                                fos.close();
                            }
                        }
                   catch( Exception e )
                   {

                   }
}
```

N.B: Take the screenshot after the `WebView` finishes loading otherwise you will get a blank screen.

Comment: This captures only webview's background as white screen. It does not have the html5 canvas element content. :-(

Comment: When I was capturing webview without using html5 canvas tag then my code was working well. After using htm5 canvas tag starts creating problem.

Answer (score 2):

I too found taking screenshots of webview displaying a HTML5 canvas directly from android app really unreliable. But there is a workaround -

You can use window.JSInterface.(params) to call an android java function from javascript. You can use canvas.toDataURL() to get a base64 encoded string of the canvas image and use it as the parameter to pass to the function. In the android function, capture the string, decode it and you have the image.

The only caveat is that the canvas area alone will come in as image and not the full device screen. Also, if the canvas didn't have a background color set, the captured png image will have a transparent background. But these can be easily solved by image manipulation from the app code.

E.g. In this game app, the game runs in a HTML5 canvas displayed in a webview. When the game finishes, a "share score" option uses the above technique to capture the canvas image to share.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skipser.flappytrex

Answer (score 0):

To capture screenshot:

```
File srcFile= driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
File targetFile = new File("D:\\Appium\\" + filename + ".png");
FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, targetFile);
System.out.println(targetFile);enter code here
```