# Screenshot of webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview, screenshot

I have used chartiq in my android app which draws chart.

However when I try to **capture** the screenshot of the **webview** through code it shows white screen.

This issue is on devices running **v4.4.3** and above.It works perfectly fine on emulator.

Comment: Take the screenshot after the WebView finishes loading otherwise you will get a blank screen.

Comment: Already done that I m doing it when chart is completely loaded in webview

Comment: so try with programmatically  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919431/take-screenshot-from-webview-in-android  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132812/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding this in manifest.xml 
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Answer (score 0):

In my case `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in manifest caused scroll problem in webview.

You may call `webview.invalidate()` before to take screenshot.

Or try this `webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`